# Where are function definitions for npm module Jasmine configured in Angular project?

Tags: angular, typescript, npm

After I create a new Angular project, *.spec.ts files allow to use Jasmine functions such as "describe", "beforeEach" and expect. I can click on them and go to their typed definitions. But where and how are they hooked up into the project? There is no import clause for them in spec.ts files.

For example logger.service.spec.ts:

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { LoggerService } from './logger.service';

describe('LoggerService', () => {
  let service: LoggerService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({});
    service = TestBed.inject(LoggerService);
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should be return input string', () => {
    let retval = service.calculate("hello");
    expect(retval).toBe("hello");
  });
});
```

clicking on describe takes me to node_modules/jasmine/index.d.ts file:

```
/**
 * Create a group of specs (often called a suite).
 * @param description Textual description of the group
 * @param specDefinitions Function for Jasmine to invoke that will define inner suites a specs
 */
declare function describe(description: string, specDefinitions: () => void): void;
```

What magic makes this possible?

Comment: Is this done by having @types/jasmine package in devDependencies?

Comment: Yes, `@types/jasmine` provides the global types, see https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/global-d-ts.html, then they'll either be explicitly listed as a source in a `tsconfig.json` or (the default) all defined types in your dependency tree will be included.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I figured.

1. @types/jasmine type definitions package needs to be installed

```
npm install @types/jasmine --save-dev
```

But that only brings files.

2. In order to take advantage of type definitions, tsconfig.{xxx}.json  should include:

```
"compilerOptions": { 
  types : [
    ..., 
    "jasmine" 
  ] 
}
```